# How to escape string in commandLink f:param name value when passing data to the server

Tags: java, jsf, escaping, myfaces

I have a problem..

```
<h:commandLink  id="editAccount"
 <f:param name="username" value="#{account.username}" />
```

This generates some `java-script` that does not escape possible special symbols in the `account.username`, and as a result it sends wrong data to server side.

As an example: if I have name: **"a/b"** - it sends **"ab"** to the server.

The possible way to fix it (what I see now) is to *escape* (wrap up) `account.username` before sending it to server side (i.e. to let `jsf` component to generate different `javascript`).

To use some parameters.. like escape = true.. But I can not find anything like this.

Ideas?

---

It seems there is bug about it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-2726

In version 1.1.7 of MyFaces. But I use 1.2.5.

I wonder if someone have has this issue in his current jsf version.

Comment: The 1.1.7 version is just version wherein the bug was found and reported. The bug report further says: *Fix Version/s: 1.1.8, 1.2.9, 2.0.1*. So, it's fixed in 1.1.8/1.2.9/2.0.1. Your 1.2.5 is older than the mentioned 1.2.9. So, just upgrade to at least 1.2.9.

Comment: Nope it does not work :( even with 1.2.9 fro my case. it generates the same not escaped javascript param. and on the server side I have this param broken

Comment: Perhaps upgrading went wrong (e.g., impl still somewhere in server work cache), or they misreported the fix version. The newest 1.2 is 1.2.12. Have you tried that as well?

Comment: checked: web-inf/lib has only 1.2.12 versions now.. and still the same sh.. thing. Probably I'm going to pass not userName but ID of the account then I do not need rely on that bug

Comment: I suggest to report to MyFaces guys. I'm not a MyFaces user so I'm not checking for you here.

Comment: looks like for JSF 1.2 escaping is only options. you can use Apache commons  StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript method